# Access folder created in windows

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, file-sharing

Is it possible to access the folder created in windows, through unix operating system (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) that is installed on a virtual machine on windows?
If yes, what is the process to access the folder?

Comment: Which is the guest and which is the host? What virtual machine technology are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, though there are more ways than one.

## **1) Shared folder option in VM manager**

Depending on the virtual machine manager, the should be an option to share a folder from the host (Windows in your case) to the virtual machine (Ubuntu).

For example

In VMware, it is under the VM settings -> Options Tab -> Shared Folder. Select "Always enabled" then under the "Folders" section click the "Add" button.

## **2) Create an Network File System (NFS)**

This is a more complex choice since it involves some setup. You will first configure Windows to share the folder via NFS (Great article from Microsoft [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324089)).

For reference:

> **To share a folder by using Nfsshare.exe:**
>
> 1. Log on to the Windows-based server by using an administrative level account.
> 2. Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then click OK.
> 3. Type the following command, and then press ENTER to share a folder to NFS clients and to allow anonymous access:
>
>    > ```
>    > nfsshare -o anon=yes share_name=drive:path
>    > ```
> 4. Type the following command, and then press ENTER to delete an NFS share:
>
>    > ```
>    >    nfsshare share_name /delete
>    > ```
> 5. Type: *nfsshare /?*, and then press ENTER to display the parameters that you can use with Nfsshare.
>
> **To share a folder by using Windows Explorer:**
>
> 1. Log on to the Windows-based server by using an administrative level account.
> 2. Start Windows Explorer.
> 3. Right-click the folder that you want to share, and then click Sharing.
> 4. Click the NFS Sharing tab, and then click Share this folder.
> 5. Configure the appropriate settings, and then click OK.
>
>    ***NOTE:*** Microsoft recommends that you install at least one User Name Mapping service on your network to map UNIX and Windows user names to each other. Please view the Kb article about User Name Mapping service below.
>
>    [324073](https://support.microsoft.com/EN-US/kb/324073) HOW TO: Configure User Name Mapping

Once you got that out of the way, you can then mount the NFS under Ubuntu as follows:

### 2.1) Create an empty directory (referred to as mount point)

sudo mkdir -p /mnt/nfs

The /mnt/nfs will be the location on ubuntu you can access the folder from but first we need to tell Ubuntu to link that folder with the NFS created on windows.

### 2.2) Mount the NFS over the created directory

This can be done by addressing the host server (Windows), which, for the purpose of this tutorial has an IP of 192.168.1.10, as shown below:

sudo mount 192.168.1.10:/ /mnt/nfs

Hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Can you add some of the details for how to setup the NFS share under Windows?  Just linking to other pages only works until the destination page goes away.

Comment: Or share the folder from mswindows and mount it as cifs on the Linux box.

Comment: @david-king, added details from link as requested